# Hiding specific icons/markers on text generated vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, display, markers, text

I'm displaying a vector layer with pois, generated from a text file:

```
lat lon icon    iconSize    iconOffset  title   description
56.030325   14.4774116666667    http://www.medinsbiologi.se/hano/Foto.png       -10.5,-25   102_1   UV-foto
```

Code to draw layer:

```
        var pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Provpunkter", 
        {
        projection: map.displayProjection,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol:   new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP(
            {
            url:        "../poi/DynPOIHano.txt",
            format:     new OpenLayers.Format.Text(
                {
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });
```

The layer shows up fine, and I have added descriptions to each poi. **Now I'd like to be able to hide some of these markers depending on icon type**, with a button somewhere else on the page. I've tried using features.style:

```
function hideFeatures() {
    var features = pois.features;
    for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
    features.style.display = 'none';
    }
    pois.redraw();
    }
```

but I don't seem to be able to identify the layers icons. Are they considered features, icons or markers? I know this can be done with the built-in OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() and by adding multiple layers, but would like to avoid that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems the "icon" in my text file was not interpreted as an attribute at all, but as an externalGraphics link. Logical off course, I just didn't get it. So now I'm able to access my icons with:

```
function hideFeatures() {
var feature = pois.features;
        for( var i = 0; i < feature.length; i++ ) {
            if (feature[i].style.externalGraphic == "http://www.medinsbiologi.se/hano/ikon/Foto.png") {
            feature[i].style= { display: 'none' };
            }
        }
        pois.redraw();
        }
```

Piece of cake... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute form the feature to determine if the feature should be visible. I haven't tested it, but i think this should work:

```
$.each(pois.features, function (index, feature) {
  if ( feature.attributes.description == 'UV-foto' )
    feature.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response! I have tried your solution without success. I slimmed it down to just  `$.each(pois.features, function (index, feature) {
    feature.style.display = 'none';
});`  Still not working. I'm calling the function hideFeatures() with an onclick event:  `button onclick="hideFeatures()"`  Might this be a problem? Am I completely missing something?

Comment: And I'm also using `pois.redraw();` after changing the style.

Comment: Can you make a working example?

Comment: My project is [here](http://www.medinsbiologi.se/hano/osm/hanokartatest.php) and the db-generated txt-file is [here](http://www.medinsbiologi.se/hano/poi/DynPOIHano.txt).  My hideFeatures function begins on line 142, and I also  tried the function on line 156, just to see if my script can access the features at all. No success, I am lost... :(